# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after calling HttpContext.SignInAsync

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core and writing a custom login.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "SomeUserName")
    // ... other stuffs
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();

var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    claimsPrincipal,
    authProperties);
```

At this point everything is OK and the auth-cookie is set in the browser,
but next time that I refresh the page, in any controller.action method, the `User.Identity.IsAhthenticated` is `false` and `User.Identity.Name` is null.

Also here is my `startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
    });

// ...
app.UseAuthentication();
```

How can I get `User.Identity.IsAhthenticated` true?

Comment: Can you confirm that `UseAuthentication` is *above* `UseMvc`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin no. It was after it. So I moved it up and it's working now.